# Force push current branch to origin if not master

Tags: bash, git

I have a git alias for force pushing current branch:

```
[alias]
    fp = "!git push -f origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\""
```

Which basically maps `fp` to a command that does a force push to the current branch, which it extracts from `git rev-parse`.

Problem: sometimes I am not paying attention and I do `git fp` when I'm on master branch. This could obviously be really bad if there are no branch protection rules in place on the repository.

I want to prevent myself from making this future mistake. How can I update my alias command to do the same thing, except only do it if the branch name is something other than `master`?

Comment: does your host support branch security policies?

Comment: @FrankThomas the problem is that I work in an organization with many repos, and make changes to many different repos. So far, most repos have a branch policy in place. And I actually accidentally did `git fp` on a few of these and got rejected. But I've also seen some repos without branch protection rules and luckily have not made this mistake (yet)

Comment: consider why you have to do force pushes so regularly that you need an alias for it. somthing is very wrong with your workflow if it is actually required.

Comment: @FrankThomas definitely just me being lazy, I can't even recall what limitation I ran into that forced me into it, thanks for calling that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition just like in regular bash:

```
[alias]
    fp = "!branch=$(git branch --show-current); [[ -z $branch || $branch = 'master' ]] && echo 'Command cannot be used on master branch or when not on branch.' || git push -f origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\""
```

This first saves the branch name from `git branch --show-current` to a var, then compares it to `master` and echoes a warning if it's a match, otherwise executes your command.

Maybe a bit more reliable version in some cases when outside of a branch:

```
[alias]
    fp = "!branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); [ \"$branch\" = 'master' ] && echo 'Command cannot be used on master branch' || git push -f origin \"$branch\""
```

But you probably don't want to attempt to push then either.

Note that these commands may not work and need more convoluted formatting (e.g. with `!f() { }` syntax) in older git versions, this is assuming the latest one as of now (`2.40`).

Comment: Interesting, I'm not very familiar with bash. Seems like the behavior is `CONDITION && TRUE_LOGIC || FALSE_LOGIC` and `[[ ... ]]` is a way to wrap complex condition? but what is `-z`

Comment: anyways this worked thanks

Comment: `[[ ]]` vs `[ ]`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/are-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-b (both could be double here). `-z`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096670/what-does-z-mean-in-bash